# Why is my PHP form not posting data correctly?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've just started using PHP forms for my website prototype, and it wasn't working so I decided to try to make a basic form example. No fancy CSS, just pure data. This is the code.

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>

  <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

  Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
  <br />
  Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The code works as far as displaying the 'Welcome ___ Your email address is: ____.
It just doesn't display the data entered in the form. For clarification as to whether my PHP works, I have tried just displaying some text and it worked fine. I use the PHP Editor phpDesigner8.
Thanks!

Comment: `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: The form must be submitted for this data to be posted

Comment: How are you using this, as an HTTP protocol or as `file:///` directly into your browser?

Comment: @AlexMaina, when I run the file on phpDesigner, I can submit the file on index.html, then it takes me to welcome.php.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, I think it's an HTTP protocol but as it's running on my files I don't know.

Comment: If from your own PC, it should be something like `http://localhost/file.xxx`. If you're already using that method and you still get nothing, try and enable error reporting and see if anything comes of it.